# Escaped Quotes in PHP for Sed Command

Tags: php, syntax, sed, quotes, libssh2

I have the following php code

```
if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, 'sed -i \'s/motd=A Minecraft Server/motd=\'.$name.\'s     Server/g\' /home/servers/runner15/server.properties
'))) {
```

But when I run it instead of replacing the text "motd=A Minecraft Server" to "motd=runner15s Server" it Changes it to motd=..s Server

It's something todo with escaping the quotes

Oh by the way $name holds runner15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic PHP strings... `'` strings do NOT interpolate variables, so your sed command contains a literal `$`, `n`, `a`, `m`, `e`, etc... That'll be interpreted as a non-existent shell varaible on the remote server, and expand to an empty string.

```
[...snip...]otd=A Minecraft Server/motd=\''.$name.'\'s [..snip...]
                                          ^-------^--- 'exit' the string in your client-side PHP
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on the vocabulary used, can you try to explain it to me a little more please? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: `$name` is not substituted in `'$name'` (single quotes!)

Answer (score 0):

Try `escapeshellcmd` before ssh2_exec. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php